# Primefaces Tabview resetting inputs

Tags: primefaces, tabview

I use primeface 3.5. I have a tabview and each tabview has got inputMasks with a form. I want to reset inputMask when i change the tab. I listen ontabchange event and reset value to="" but    bean reset values but View doesn't reset.

```
        <p:tabView id="tabViewOS"  binding="#{docData.tabView}" dynamic="true" cache="true"  rendered="#{userData.opRendered}">



            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{docData.onTabChange}"  immediate="true"/>

            <p:tab id="tab1" title="AB">


                       <h:form id="ABForm">

                       <h:panelGrid id="abgrid" columns="3" cellpadding="5">


                        <h:outputText value="AB NO: " />
                        <p:inputMask value="#{docData.abNo}" mask="999-99999999"
                            id="ABinput" required="true"


                        </p:inputMask>
                        <p:message id="msgAB" for="ABinput" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />


                        <h:outputText value="" />
                        <p:commandButton value="GETİR" style="float:right;" ajax="false"
                            action="#{docData.getDoc}" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                       </h:form>


            </p:tab>





  public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {

      this.activeTabIndex = tabView.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab());
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();   
      System.out.println(this.activeTabIndex);
      this.abNo="";




      documents.clear();


}
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: If you would like to save the index of the active tab in your bean just use the attribute `activeIndex` of the `p:tabView`. Why are you doing `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse(); `? And to achieve the update of the tab use `dynamic="true" cache="false"`. `cache` defaults to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way the event is called. Instead of **`immediate=true`** use **`process="@this"`**.

Change this:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{docData.onTabChange}"  immediate="true"/>
```

To this:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{docData.onTabChange}"  process="@this" update="ABinput"/>
```

Comment: `process="@this"` is the default value anyway and so `immediate="true"` does actually nothing and is completely unnecessary. The thing here is, that the part of the view where the values have to be updated (in this case resetted) has to be updated, after a tab change.

Comment: with immediate=true i can stay same tab after click the button. my knowledge is not deep about jsf as you see =) if it run i dont touch code

Comment: Primefaces documentation suggests that the default value for **process** is **null**. (Primefaces user guide 3.5 pg. 19). And it declares the component(s) to process in partial request. I think that submitting the whole form can trigger validation on fields that are not meant to be part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

i guess  as you said   -dynamic="true" cache="false">- is solve my problem. Actually I tested program faulty, my problem has already solved. I think in my case cause of this situation cache=false  as documentation said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the primefaces documentation on `p:tabView`. On the one hand you have the property `dynamic` which specifies if the content of a tab is loaded with AJAX when you select some tag. On the other hand there is the property `cache` which specifies wheter or not the content of a tab is only dynamically loaded the first time you select a tab.

So regarding this informations setting `dynamic="true" cache="false"` on the `p:tabView` should do the trick for you.

Another interesting property for you would be `activeIndex`. As I see you are setting the index of the active tab manually on tab change. If you can submit tabview on tabchange and you have set `activeIndex="#{docData.activeTabIndex}"` the active tabindex is tracked automatically. Have a look at the documentation if this fits your requirements.